# Layout propertices programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I have relativelayout as container, there i have set text and image, next i addView() this relativelayout twice to one linear layout, everything is fine but i cant separate the two relativelayouts they are alWays stick one to another, here is the code:

LinearLayout

```
layout = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

ll.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
layout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
layout.setLayoutParams(ll);
layout.setId(i);

layout.addView(m1.box);
layout.addView(m2.box);
```

where m1 and m2 are:
RelativeLayout:

```
box = new RelativeLayout(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rl = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

rl.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
rl.width = 125;
rl.height = 125;

box.setId(i);
box.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
box.setBackgroundColor(color1);
box.setLayoutParams(rl);
//add some text and image
```

How to separate m1 from m2? Now they look like OO i need to add space O_O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this doesn't work because the parent layout is a `LinearLayout`, and the `LayoutParams` you defined are of `RelativeLayout`. the `LayoutParams` should match the type of the parent and not the child, because they tell the parent how and where to place it's children.

Second, use `addView(View v, LayoutParams lp)` instead of `addView(View v)` to prevent this kind of mistakes.